# Convert tiff (with path) to png and remove background (transparent) - with Imagemagick in PHP

Tags: php, shell, imagemagick, png, tiff

So, i have a lot of tiff files and I want to generate thumbnails of them. This thumbnails must have a transparent background.

All tiffs have: a **white background** and a **path along the object** (e.g. a can of a coke) and are saved as CMYK.

So i tried a lot of `convert` commands (like [these](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25194) and also php `Imagick::clipPath` but nothing worked very well (background still there/corrupt image).

```
convert a.tif -clip -resize 800x600 a.png
convert a.tif -clip -alpha transparent +clip -channel A -resize 800x600 a.png
```

also this php code:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick('a.tif');
$image->clipPath();    
$image->setImageFormat('png');    
$image->thumbnailImage(800, 600, true);
$image->writeImage('a.png');
```

**[here](http://goo.gl/c1B1dC)** is an example tif file

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this.

**EDIT:**

The best result returns this:
`convert test.tif -clip -alpha transparent 1.png`

But it saves the background and not the clipped object. ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZQyf.jpg))

Comment: "Corrupt image" means exactly that -- you got random trash instead of a recognizable image, with or without background?

Comment: it's clipped (transparent background) but there are some lines of black pixels or/and the main object also has some removed edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it after trying it for hours.

`convert can.tif -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque result.png`

So it must be executed with e.g. `shell_exec` - I didn't found any possible solution to do it with the Imagick-PHP class.

The problem was an old imagemagick version and also the wrong order of command attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the PHP imagick extension is to replicate the same set of commands:

```
$imagick->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_TRANSPARENT);
$imagick->clipImage();
$imagick->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I remember to used this code already - but in my hosting enviroment the ImageMagick version was pretty old and generated broken results. Due no access to the php.ini file I switched to the command line solution.